Can I directly do this type of switching in my inverter circuit?

So our project is based upon using a solar panel as the main source, but in case it fails, we need the circuit to automatically switch to the government supply which we'll be converting into 12V DC. Can this be achieved directly and simply by a relay circuit like the one in the image? Or we need a sensor and a micro-controller like Arduino for the job? Also, are there any changes that I need to make in the circuit?

No you can’t do that.
At night electricity flows from the 12V through the lamp and the relay coil causing the relay to buzz or chatter.
Changes, well everything, add diodes on the solar output so that current cannot flow into it from the 12 V.
Move the relay contacts to be between the solar, the 12 V, and the load.

This won't work. As soon as the solar panel doesn't provide enough power to  keep the relays switched on, the relays will fall off, connect utility power which will flow trough your load and the coil in series and might destroy your solar cell (because solar cells don't like being driven in reverse). But the most important thing is, that the coil of your relays get's energized which will turn off utility power again...
Solution? Much easier:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The answer suggests a solution which uses two Shottky diodes to wire-OR either the Utility or Solar supply. The question body contains the following requirement:

our project is based upon using a solar panel as the main source, but in case it fails, we need the circuit to automatically switch to the government supply`

Which implies the solar supply is to be used in preference. By using diodes to wire-OR the supply, when the Solar supply is available the Utility supply may be providing the supply depending upon:

Which of the Solar or Utility supplies has the "higher" of the nominal 12 V.
The forward biased voltage drop of the Shottky diodes, which may not be exactly matched.

Whereas the following should give preference to using the Solar supply:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
C1 is included to try and maintain the load voltage over the relay operate / release time. The actual capacitor value to be used would depend upon:

The load current
The relay operate / release time, which should be specified in the relay datasheet.

One potential weakness of the relay based circuit is that depending how quickly the Solar Panel voltage changes between night / day the voltage might hover around value which closes the relay and result in the relay "chattering" which could reduce the life of the relay.
